# Python regex to match a specific word

Tags: python, regex, match

I want to match all lines in a test report, which contain words 'Not Ok'.
Example line of text :

```
'Test result 1: Not Ok -31.08'
```

I tried this:

```
filter1 = re.compile("Not Ok")
for line in myfile:                                     
    if filter1.match(line): 
       print line
```

which should work according to http://rubular.com/, but I get nothing at the output. Any idea, what might be wrong? Tested various other parameters, like "." and "^Test" , which work perfectly.

Comment: Why regex if it's a specific string? Why not `if "Not Ok" in line:`?

Comment: BTW, `re.match()` only matches at the start of the string.

Comment: I was sure match could not only do the start of the string.. shouldn't $ match the end of line?

Comment: Maybe I was being unclear: `re.match("a")` is the same as `re.search("^a")`. `re.match("Not Ok")` will return `True` for `"Not Ok Joe!"` and `False` for `"It's Not Ok!"`.

Comment: ah, I see. Wasn't so clear from Python documentation. Learning something new every day!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should use `re.search` here not `re.match`.

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) on `re.match`:

> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead.

If you're looking for the exact word `'Not Ok'` then use `\b` word boundaries, otherwise 
if you're only looking for a substring `'Not Ok'` then use simple : `if 'Not Ok' in string`.

```
>>> strs = 'Test result 1: Not Ok -31.08'
>>> re.search(r'\bNot Ok\b',strs).group(0)
'Not Ok'
>>> match = re.search(r'\bNot Ok\b',strs)
>>> if match:
...     print "Found"
... else:
...     print "Not Found"
...     
Found
```

Comment: indeed, this works, even without all extra \b stuff. Thanks! I also found that re.findall worked in this case.

Comment: @casper without `\b` it'll return `True` for something like this as well: `'KNot Oke'`. `re.findall` returns a list of all non-overlapping matches, for checking purpose `re.search` is the best choice.

Answer (score 6):

You could simply use,

```
if <keyword> in str:
    print('Found keyword')
```

Example:

```
if 'Not Ok' in input_string:
    print('Found string')
```

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely no need to use RegEx in this case! Just use:

```
s = 'Test result 1: Not Ok -31.08'
if s.find('Not Ok') > 0 : 
    print("Found!")
```

or as already mentioned:

```
if 'Not Ok' in s:
    print("Found!")
```