# Python3, re.match with list

Tags: python, django

I read this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17090205/6426449

And I made a list that cannot be used on username in django.

**list** : `FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST = ['admin', 'master', 'owner']`

So I made a code like this :

**views.py**

```
def username_choice(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']    
        for item in forbidden.FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST:
            match = re.search("r'\b"+item+"\b'", username)
            if match:
                return JsonResponse({'result': item + 'banned username'})
```

But It seems that it does not work.

Maybe I think, `match = re.search("r'\b"+item+"\b'", username)` Here is problem.

How can I fix that?

Comment: how are you entering the username from the frontend?

Comment: you better check this thing in the form validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use `in`:

```
forbidden = ['admin', 'master', 'owner']
username = request.POST['username']
match = [nm for nm in forbidden if nm in username]
if match:
    # part of the username is in the forbidden list.
```

Example in IPython:

```
In [1]: forbidden = ['admin', 'master', 'owner']

In [2]: username = 'owner123'

In [3]: match = [nm for nm in forbidden if nm in username]

In [4]: match
Out[4]: ['owner']
```

Comment: I like that this approach doesn't use regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
def username_choice(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']    
        for item in forbidden.FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST:
          if re.search(r'\b'+str(item)+'\\b', username, re.I):
              return JsonResponse({'result': item + 'banned username'})
```

Comment: Thanks Exprator, but what if `username = admin123` ? I want to also ban all username with any of forbidden_username_list.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this statement:

```
match = re.search(r'[%s]+' % item, username, re.I)
```

instead of this:

```
match = re.search("r'\b"+item+"\b'", username)
```