# How to convert Python [... for ... in ... if ...] to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, code-conversion

In my previous question, some kind man gave me a good answer of check username.

This code checks whether `username` has some forbidden words.

Python:

```
FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST = ['admin', 'master', 'owner']

for item in forbidden.FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST:
    match = [nm for nm in FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST if nm in username]
    if match:
        return JsonResponse({'result': item + 'banned username'})
```

I converted this code to JavaScript but some code is too hard for me to convert.

JavaScript:

```
for (item in FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST){
    match = [nm for nm in FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST if nm in username]
    //Here match = [...] code is hard for me to convert 
    if (match){
        console.log('exist')
    }
}
```

How can I convert this code to JavaScript?

Comment: Can you put some comments explaining what this line does `match = [nm for nm in FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST if nm in username]` ?

Comment: You've not made an effort to convert the code. You've replaced `:` with `{}`.

Comment: @KenWhite: "...but somehow that did not work" 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex in ES5:

```js
var FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST = ['admin', 'master', 'owner'],
    username = "master",
    match = false;

match = FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST.some(function(pattern) {
  return new RegExp(pattern).test(username)
});

if (match) {
  console.log(username, 'exists');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
 const forbidden = ['admin', 'master', 'owner'];
 const username ="imanadmin;)";
 const found = forbidden.find(word => username.includes(word));
 if(found) return res.json({'result': found + ' banned username'});
```

Just `find` the forbidden word that is `included` in the username. (`res.json` is part of [`Express`](http://expressjs.com/de/) which you might use for setting up a server)

Comment: [try it](http://jsbin.com/hacoxixevi/edit?console)

Comment: Thanks for your comment It works well but another answer was better for me

Comment: @tpuchingtwist actually not but thats another thing ;) glad to help...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to check if `item` is in `username` or not,

If `username` is an **array** (*It seems to be array based on your previous question*)

```
match = !!username.filter( s => item.indexOf(s) != -1 ).length;
```

or use `some`

```
match = username.some( s => item.indexOf(s) != -1 );
```

**Note**

I am using indexOf since it seems from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989737/python3-re-match-with-list) you wanted to match `owner123` with `owner` as well.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you're looking for a match or submatch of the user name. Given the error message provided, a submatch doesn't seem to make sense, so I'll assume an exact match is actually needed.

If you do want a submatch, use the `.includes()` method on `username`

```js
const username = "master";
const FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST = ['admin', 'master', 'owner'];

const match = FORBIDDEN_USERNAME_LIST.some(n => n === username);

if (match) {
  console.log(username, 'exists');
}
```

Comment: @touchingtwist: Why do you think a regex is better than a much simpler text search using `.includes()` or `.indexOf()`? It'll be slower and can break depending on what characters are valid for your user names.